# Missing emails when change order status in queue

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Some time ago, we implemented a functionality that checks if a comment has been added to the order. If not added, the status changes automatically to inprogress. The code looks like this:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'changeOrderStatus',
    ];
}

public function changeOrderStatus(CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent $event): void
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    if (null === $order->getCustomerComment()) {
        $this->stateMachineRegistry->transition(new Transition(
            OrderDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
            $order->getId(),
            'process',
            'stateId'
        ), $event->getContext());
    }
}
```

After some time, in order not to block the main thread, we decided to move this function to the queue. This shortened the ordering time. however, if the same code is already executed in the queue handler, then the mail is not sent.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'changeOrderStatus',
    ];
}

public function changeOrderStatus(CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent $event): void
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    if (null === $order->getCustomerComment()) {
        $this->bus->dispatch(new ChangeStatusMessage(
            $event->getOrder()->getId(),
            $event->getContext()
        ));
    }
}
```

In the hendler message, we execute the same status change code.

```
public function handle($message): void
{
    $this->stateMachineRegistry->transition(new Transition(
        OrderDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
        $message->getOrderId(),
        'process',
        'stateId'
    ), $message->getContext());
}
```

Comment: I assume the transition of states works however, just no mail is sent? Could you show some more of your code, like the implementation of the message and how it is dispatched? Maybe also an example of how you did it synchronously to maybe find differences causing this issue.

Comment: @dneustadt I updated ticket